# Geopy: Create separate latitude and longitude dataframe columns with address

Tags: python, geolocation, location

I have a column with site addresses and I'm trying to create two separate latitude and longitude columns with geopy. Can anyone please help me out with that? Much appreciated!

Dataframe

```
Site     Address   
 1       South Krishnapur, 89, BERULIA ROAD, Savar, Dhaka
 2       8, Malibagh chowdhury para, Ramna, Dhaka, Dhaka
```

Desired output

```
Site     Address                                               Latitude         Longitude
 1       South Krishnapur, 89, BERULIA ROAD, Savar, Dhaka      (Coordinates)    (Coordinates)
 2       8, Malibagh chowdhury para, Ramna, Dhaka, Dhaka       (Coordinates)    (Coordinates)
```

Code

```
pip install geopy

from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim()
location = geolocator.geocode("South Krishnapur, 89, BERULIA ROAD, Savar, Dhaka")
```

Comment: Did you find out how to do this?